# How to use temp variable to replace specific path in xp_fileexist function

Tags: sql-server

I use the following code to check if one file exists in a folder and it works with returning 1.

Code A:

```
DECLARE @result INT
EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist 'C:\Users\folder\123.json', @result OUTPUT
SELECT @result
```

Now I want to a variable to represent the path and create the following code, but it does not work, returning error message saying

> Msg 22027, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Usage:  EXECUTE xp_fileexist  [,  OUTPUT]

Code B:

```
DECLARE @rootfolder AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @file AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
declare @jsonfilename varchar(100)

set @rootfolder = 'C:\Users\folder\'
set @jsonfilename = '123.json'
set @file = concat(@rootfolder, @jsonfilename);

DECLARE @result INT
EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @file, @result OUTPUT
select @result
```

If I print @file, it's exactly the same as what I want. Not sure what is the problem and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `xp_fileexist` does not accept `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` as input.  I get the same error as you (SQL Server 2017 Ent.) but specifying the character length works:

```
DECLARE @rootfolder AS VARCHAR(max),
        @file AS NVARCHAR(255)
declare @jsonfilename varchar(100)

set @rootfolder = 'C:\Users\folder\'
set @jsonfilename = '123.json'
set @file = concat(@rootfolder, @jsonfilename);

DECLARE @result INT
EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @file, @result OUTPUT
select @result
```

Starting in SQL Server 2017 there is also a new DMF `sys.dm_os_file_exists()` that does the same thing and does support `MAX`:

```
DECLARE @rootfolder AS VARCHAR(max),
        @file AS NVARCHAR(max)
declare @jsonfilename varchar(100)

set @rootfolder = 'C:\Users\folder\'
set @jsonfilename = '123.json'
set @file = concat(@rootfolder, @jsonfilename);

DECLARE @result INT
SELECT @result = file_exists FROM sys.dm_os_file_exists(@file)
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks squillman. Any idea about the difference between nvarchar(255) and nvarchar(max), and the true reason?

Comment: No idea, other than maybe a bug in the proc.  And at the risk of stating the obvious, make sure you use a variable length long enough to hold the entire file path you're trying to check or else you will get incorrect results with no error.

Comment: @Harry Also, see my update.  If you are using SQL Server 2017 or newer you can use a new DMF and avoid the issue.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work with UNC/network paths

Comment: @Mahesh That would be a different issue unrelated to the question here